# jQuery Json response printing html tags

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I do:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $value = isset($_GET['send_request']) ? $_GET['send_request'] : false ;

    if ($value) {
        echo $value;
        return;
    }
    ?>


    <a href="javascript: test()">A</a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test() {

            // data to send
            var data = { send_request: 'Yes'}

            request = $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                data: data
            });

            request.done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the console I am getting:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Yes
```

Why is this?

Comment: It's because that's the HTML you output before your PHP executes. Place the PHP *before* the HTML, or in its own file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that your php code executes after you have already outputted this part:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

Move the php code to the top of the page and it will fix this :)
Keep in mind that when you execute php script, php will not ommit html, but rather consider it output and just carry on :)

Comment: Thanks! Well explained!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to move your PHP codes to a separate PHP file and specify it's path in the `url` option of your ajax function. That new PHP file should of course not contain *HTML* before your PHP codes as already pointed out.

Comment: I was just testing out something quickly. Generally yes I would separate stuff.